# How to send a mongodb BinData object to the response in meteor?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm wondering how to send a MongoDB BinData object to the nodejs response in Meteor. My route looks something like this:

```
Router.route('/profiles/:owner/pictures/:_id', function() {
  var file = Files.findOne(this.params._id);
  this.response.end(file.data);
}, {
  name: 'profile.image',
  where: 'server'
});
```

When I try to load a URL that I expect to return an image I get this NodeJS error:

```
TypeError: Argument must be a string at getSize
```

Comment: In the end I skipped this approach in favor of [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS)

Answer (score 0):

In your name key you're looking for a string instead of an argument.

Comment: The error happens regardless of the route is set up, and goes away if I send a string as the response. I'm looking for a way to serialize a mongo BinData into the response.